# how to zoom out in PL/SQL Developer 12(64bit)

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I'm new to coding world. I have started to use SQL developer at my current role. I don't know how to zoom out.

[image]

I looked into tool to find preference option, I couldn't find it though.

Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks,
Elly

Comment: that's not SQL Developer, that's Allround's PL/SQL Developer - completely different application, i re-titled your question and updated your tags to reflect this

Comment: probably just upgrade to 13, they talk about better support for this in v13 here https://www.allroundautomations.com/products/pl-sql-developer/features/new-features-pl-sql-13-0/

Answer (score -1):

If the application is DPI-unaware, there's little you can do it make it otherwise -- the developers chose to build it that way.

The only two things you can try are:

- Start it with DPI-unaware compatibility settings: [image]
- Set your monitor's DPI to 100% (with the obvious drawback): [image]